# C++. Meaning of var1 = new (_field) Constructor()

Tags: c++

I found this construction reading someone's else C++ code:

```
_worklist = new (_arena) Block_List();
```

I'm a little rusty on my C++, can someone explain what is going on here? I don't understand what this code is doing.

**EDIT**:

_arena is a field of type [Arena](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hsx24/hotspot/file/ed3ac73a70ab/src/share/vm/memory/allocation.hpp#l282).

**EDIT 2**:

And here is the code of [Block_List](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hsx24/hotspot/file/ed3ac73a70ab/src/share/vm/opto/block.hpp#l75)

**Edit 3**:
My bad, I now understand  should have provide more context, here is the whole code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hsx24/hotspot/file/ed3ac73a70ab/src/share/vm/opto/live.cpp#l52

Comment: Somewhere there is an overloaded `operator new` that accepts whatever type `_arena` is in addition to the size parameter.

Comment: it is a "placement new"
you can read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: This depends very much on what `_arena` is. It *could* be placement-new, or something completely different.

Comment: @nikniknik2016 not enough info to decide if it's the standard placement new.

Comment: Either the other developer typedef'd something as _arena type, or there is an overload of standard new, taking additional input

Comment: How can I know is a placement new by looking at the code?

Comment: @ElMarce, that depends on what `_arena` is.

Comment: The fact that `_arena` is a field doesn't tell us anything. What matters is its type.

Comment: It's *not* placement new, instead there is (somewhere in your source) an overload of `operator new` which takes a second argument of type `Arena`. That's really all we can say. Search all your code for `operator new`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, it's not the standard one, but it's a placement new-expression.

Comment: [Documentation on overloading/providing own `new` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is a good old placement new. `_arena` is an `Arena*`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot No, it's a custom `operator new` that takes an argument of type `Arena*`.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot The OP doesn't really provide very much information, but nowhere has it been said that `_arena` is a pointer. The only information we have is that `_arena` is an instance of `Arena`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placement syntax is used to call a custom `operator new` that takes additional arguments. In this case, `Block_List` is derived from `ResourceObj`, and `ResourceObj` contains the following function:

```
void* operator new(size_t size, Arena *arena) {
    address res = (address)arena->Amalloc(size);
    DEBUG_ONLY(set_allocation_type(res, ARENA);)
    return res;
}
```

The expression `new (_arena) Block_List();` will call this `operator new`, passing in the required size and the value that was passed in. The function returns the address to use for the object.

Comment: Your answer is entirely correct, but it might be helpful to distinguish between:  "placement new" (where the object is created in a pre-allocated buffer without any need for a custom `operator new`); "a placement new expression" (where a custom `operator new` is called to allocate memory).  What we have here is the latter.

Comment: @MartinBonner Those are not official or accurate terms. The standard defines a placement syntax which includes the parentheses after `new`, and a placement `operator new` which takes extra arguments. There are also predefined placement `operator new` versions which take arguments of type `void*` (to set the address) or `nothrow_t` (to avoid `bad_alloc` exceptions), but they are merely specific instances of the placement new operator.

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't realized that.